# Is it possible to connect to Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard's built in vnc server at a low color depth from Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, vnc

If I attempt to connect to Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard's built in vnc server at a low color depth from Windows, the client bombs after connecting. It only works when I set it to the highest color depth. I've tried with at least 3 windows VNC clients. Any ideas? There some setting I can set in Mac OS X?

It takes about 20 seconds to repaint the screen with my current connection and high bit depth setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with the builtin VNC server.  [Vine Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/) allows you to change the bit depth that clients connect at though.

Comment: This is my current workaround. Vine Server is pretty easy to setup. I'd really like to be able to do it with the builtin though :(

Comment: This is no longer supported by the developer and it hasn't been updated in years. It no longer runs on current versions of OSX.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you can't lower the color depth with the default vnc server. I won't assert it, because maybe that behaviour could be changed using a console command.

I'd recommend installing another VNC server in mac, like http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/

Comment: There *is* a console command to expose more options to the built in screen sharing.  Though it doesn't help Alex, I'm afraid.  If anyone is interested, they can read http://www.macworld.com/article/131094/2007/12/screensharepower.html
although if you're using 10.5.5+, you need to read the updated instructions linked from that page.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in vnc seems to have very little configurability that I can see.

As an alternative, you can try using [osxvnc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/) which I believe allows different bit depths

Answer (score 1):

You can from the client side switch to High Color(16 bits) but not Low Color(8 bits).  You can also enable JPEG compression.  With both of these options on the sessions speed of to me from completely unusable(~45s for initial screen draw and ~5s lag on clicking menus) to quite usable(<5s for initial screen draw and <1s lag on clicking  menus).

Note that these times are for connecting from a remote computer to my home iMac on a cable modem.  Also this is running dual screens witch get sent out even though I only use the primary one on VNC.  I have yet to figure out a way to switch off the secondary screen in VNC and its to troublesome to unplug it.

Answer (score 0):

I use both.  I find the built-in VNC server in OS X offers the most compatibility with keystrokes.  I use it when I'm on the local network.  When using VPN (much slower), I setup Vine Server ("System Server" mode) on a non-standard port # (say 5905), with a much lower color resolution, so the screen doesn't take 30 seconds to redraw whenever I click something.

Then I just ask my client to connect over the appropriate port: 5900 calls the built-in VNC server (for high rez use on the LAN), & 5905 calls Vine Server (for screen update speed over VPN).  Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and started using LogMeIn's free edition.